# Android ProgressBar doesn't show up in Presentation

Tags: android, presentation

I have a `ProgressBar` with a spinner as the drawable set in the XML. The preview shows the design as expected. But the `ProgressBar` doesn't actually show up when the [Presentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation) is launched.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backgroundImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/main_screen_bg"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/webViewLoadingContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressCircle"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/theme_progress_circle" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/purchase_order_single_wait_txt"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_60" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The element seems to take the assigned width and height but doesn't actually show up. What could be the cause for this?

Edit:
So found the issue. The drawable was as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="8"
        android:useLevel="false" >

        <size
            android:height="76dip"
            android:width="76dip" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Seems like the `endColor` and `startColor` properties being set via the Theme was the issue.

Any tips on how to use the Theme properties in Presentations?

Comment: Please, if you use ConstraintLayout which is good try not to nest so many ViewGroups inside (FrameLayout  and LinearLayouts in this case), I bet they are not necessary. Nesting views is performance killer with these old traditional android views.

Comment: Are you sure you are not changing for example the visibility of the webview by code? Cause the way it's done the webview would be over the other elements hiding them, for example.

Comment: @BuddyChrist I tried having the webViewLoadingContent layout enabled throughout. But the ProgressBar doesn't show up.